# Abstraction of a model in presence of submodels

Tags: c#, oop, software-design

I came to this situation in the process of refactoring my project.

There's a model class, which contains several submodels:

```
public class Model
{
    public Submodel_A SM { get; set; }
    public Submodel_B SM { get; set; }
    public Submodel_C SM { get; set; }
}

public class Submodel_A { /* contains only properties */ }
public class Submodel_B { /* contains only properties */ }
public class Submodel_C { /* contains only properties */ }
```

Now, I need to move the `Model` to a separate assembly. To do so, I'd like the model to implement an interface, say, `IModel`. But here I'm stuck, because of the submodels:

```
interface IModel
{
    Submodel_A SM { get; set; }
    Submodel_B SM { get; set; }
    Submodel_C SM { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously, using `Submodel_*` classes themselves is not a solution. Do I really have to have an interface per submodel? Or, maybe, it's better to hide them from the interface somehow? (Hiding is an option, since submodels only carry some data and have virtually no other functionality).

Comment: Why not use a generic interface? IModel<T>

Comment: When you say "submodel", are you saying the `Submodel_*` classes derive from `Model`? If so, that's where your design problem is.

Comment: @GrantWinney it's not a solution because it prevents me from reversing the assembly dependencies. I want the code which uses the model to depend only on the model interface assembly. Having submodels in the interface makes it depend on the implementation assembly.

Comment: @itsme86 Nope, they are unrelated classes (as shown).

Comment: The interface only needs to contain what you want to expose. If the submodels are specific to the inner workings of `Model` (or are only relevant within `Model`'s assembly) then you don't need to include them in the interface at all.

Comment: @JLRishe they do expose public data, in a hierarchically structured manner. But now I'm unsure if it's worth the burden of the hierarchical interface boilerplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I ended up in having interfaces for everything, gathered in a dedicated assembly. Yes, almost all other modules depend on it now, but it hasn't brought any trouble so far...